# Failed to start Automation Anywhere Control Room: Bad Gateway

Tags: windows-server-2012, sql-server-2017, automationanywhere

After I installed Automation Anywhere 11 with SQL Server 2017 on windows server 2012, I could not launch the control room getting bad gateway message.

Could anyone help identifying the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible reasons for this to happen, the one most easy to miss is your SQL login not having permissions to access your DB.

Open your SQL Management Studio and check that your have login logging enabled (`Server Properties -> Security -> Login auditing`). It is set to `Failed only` by default, you can change it to `Both successful and failed` if you wish.

[image]

Then attempt to login to Control Room and then check the logs.

[image]

You are most likely going to see an account trying and failing to connect to the DB. Give that account sufficient privileges and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I think the problem is that I try to install AA on VM of 3 G Ram and it is not sufficient, it takes forever to make the install now, then it fails telling me could not complete write in insightbot db and i see in logs "A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out.This may result in performance degradation"

Comment: Yes, that's another very likely possibility. New AA is extremely resource intensive. I had a call with one of their engineers and they told me that for AA to be working all of the background services need to be running. But if there is not enough RAM, some of them will not start, without any error notification to the user. The recommended setup is I think 16 GB. I got it working on 8 GB, but 3 seems like way too little.

Comment: I can confirm. I feel even 8GB RAM is too little to operate 'smoothly'.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing something similar after I restarted my `Automation Anywhere Control Room Service` from services.msc as adviced in AA forum for getting this error.

> grid is invalid state...contact administrator

But, after I restarted the `Automation Anywhere Enterprise Auto Login Service V11` service the control room worked fine.